# How to document Structure fields in Python using Sphinx

Tags: python, ctypes, python-sphinx

I have python classes declared in the following way:

```
class Foo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("vr", c_double),
        ("vi", c_double),
        ("vm", c_float),
        ("va", c_float)]
```

They are subclasses of `Structure` because I am using `ctypes` to wrap a C DLL and these are the mirrors of the C structs. I can't figure out how to generate documentation for these. The auto-generated documentation is very ugly and useless:

    `va
    Structure/Union member
    vi
    Structure/Union member
    vm
    Structure/Union member
    vr
    Structure/Union member`

Does anyone have any idea how I can define these?

I just wanted to clarify that `_fields_` sort of doesn't actually exist. It is a special feature of `ctypes` that provides a way of declaring members in a way that you can line up with a C struct. So if I instantiate the object: `foo = Foo()` then I would never access `_fields_` but rather the members directly as if they were just declared as normal instance variables. So, using the instance above, to access `vr` I would do something like `print foo.vr`.

What is tripping me up here is that I want to add descriptions of those variables. The auto-generation calls them "structure/union members" which makes sense, since they are members of a structure, but I want to add a more descriptive and useful description. For example, I would like to add a note that "vm" is magnitude and "va" is angle.

Comment: The `Foo` class should have a docstring. In that docstring you can describe the `_fields_` variable. Perhaps by simply including its definition verbatim. That is what I can think of.

Comment: Thanks. That seems like a very reasonable suggestion and I'll try that out.

Comment: "*I want to add descriptions of those variables*". You can do that, and I have provided examples. What exactly is tripping you up?

Comment: I just have been swamped with other work. I will happily accept your answer once I have tested out your suggestions and confirm that they work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I finally tested that method and it doesn't work. I can document parameters of the class but it still includes the auto-generated ones from the structure.

Comment: Do you use the `:undoc-members:` option to `automodule`? Because if I do I get the auto-generated output that you don't like.

Comment: That fixed it! Removing `:undoc-members:` got rid of all of the auto-generated stuff so I am now free to overwrite it. This is a bit annoying because that means I have to go and document everything now instead of doing it incrementally but at least it's taken care of now. Feel free to pop that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unwanted auto-generated documentation disappears if the `:undoc-members:` option to the `automodule` directive is removed.

---

Add a docstring to the `Foo` class. In that docstring, describe the the `_fields_` class variable. Perhaps the easiest way to do that is to simply include the definition verbatim. Something like this:

```
class Foo(Structure):
    """
    This class is used to...

    The ``_fields_`` class variable is defined as follows::

      _fields_ = [
         ("vr", c_double),
         ("vi", c_double),
         ("vm", c_float),
         ("va", c_float)]
    """

    _fields_ = [
        ("vr", c_double),
        ("vi", c_double),
        ("vm", c_float),
        ("va", c_float)]
```

Here is another way of doing it that might be closer to what you want:

```
class Foo(Structure):
    """
    This class is used to...

    Instances of this class have the following members:

    * ``vr`` (type: c_double): whatever
    * ``vi`` (type: c_double): something
    * ``vm`` (type: c_float): magnitude 
    * ``va`` (type: c_float): angle
    """

    _fields_ = [
        ("vr", c_double),
        ("vi", c_double),
        ("vm", c_float),
        ("va", c_float)]
```

Yet another alternative (using [info fields](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#info-field-lists)):

```
class Foo(Structure):
    """
    This class is used to...

    :ivar vr: whatever
    :vartype vr: c_double
    :ivar vi: something
    :vartype vi: c_double
    :ivar vm: magnitude
    :vartype vm: c_float
    :ivar va: angle
    :vartype va: c_float
    """

    _fields_ = [
        ("vr", c_double),
        ("vi", c_double),
        ("vm", c_float),
        ("va", c_float)]
```

Comment: but, to clarify, `_fields_` is a special member used in ctypes/structure. basically you are defining members of that class. so I can access them in an instance of the `Foo` class like so: `foo.vm = 0.5`

Comment: I see that you have updated the question. '*but I want to add a more descriptive and useful description. For example, I would like to add a note that "vm" is magnitude and "va" is angle.*'. Then just go ahead an add the descriptive and useful description to the docstring. Or is there a problem with that?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I will test that out again. I believe I tried that when I first got started and something about what I did didn't work.